# Регулярка на js для HH:MM время от 00:00 до 23:59

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Регулярка на js для HH:MM время от 00:00 до 23:59

Comment: Вроде простейшая регулярка, в чем проблема?

Comment: Да нет проблемы. Плотно не работал, год назад что-то читал.

Comment: ^([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)$ Эта подойдёт?

Comment: Есть попроще `/\d{2}:\d{2}/`

Comment: а оно не пропустит 25:99 Вижу 2 цифры двоеточие и еще 2 цифры?

Comment: Подойдёт. Стоило задавать вопрос? Быстрее было бы запустить и проверить...

Comment: ^([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$ вот эта лучше. Я раньше не пользовался онлайн калькуляторами. Сначала вопрос написал, а потом на таком же сайте увидел, что есть такие. Спасибо всем

Comment: Чего то я не догнал??? Посмотрите в консоль  `console.log("bla-bla 23:55 bla-bla".replace(/^([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$/,'zzz'))`

Comment: а если так console.log("23:55".replace(/^([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$/,'zzz'));

Comment: Ну если в принимаемой строке, больше ничего нет... то да

Comment: А если есть.... в общем ответ ниже

Comment: если есть то, нужно писать в выражении что может быть что угодно в начале и что угодно в конце. Я так думаю...

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 5):

```
^(?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

Подробности:

- `^` - начало строки

  - `(?:` - начало незахватывающей группы
  - `0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]` - захватывающие подмаски
  - `)` - конец незахватывающей группы
  - `:` - символ двоеточия (разделения часов и минут)
  - `[0-5]` - захватывающая подмаска числа от 0 до 5
  - `[0-9]` - захватывающая подмаска числа от 0 до 9
- `$` - конец строки

Answer (score 3):

Если в строке помимо времени имеются другие данные, то эта регулярка больше подходит

```
/(([2][0-3])|([0-1][0-9])):([0-5][0-9])/
```

К примеру -

```js
console.log("bla-bla 23:17 bla-bla".replace(/(([2][0-3])|([0-1][0-9])):([0-5][0-9])/,'zzz'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$
```

Формат от `00:00` до `23:59`

```
/^([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$/.test('22:10') // истина
/^([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$/.test('Бла 22:10 бла') // ложь
```